# How can I use the Waypoints script in other scripts for different waypoints and agents?

Tags: unity, c#

The main goal is to be able to use the SimpleAI script from many other scripts like the BodyScan script and make different agents to travel in different waypoints. For example in BodyScene there will be 5 agents that will move between 10 waypoints. In another script let's call it testing there will be 20 agents and they will move between different waypoints.

Waypoints class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Waypoints
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
}
```

The BodyScan script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BodyScan : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<NavMeshAgent> agents;
    public GameObject transporter;
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    [Range(20, 300)]
    public int timeVisit = 20;
    public string nextVisitTime;

    private List<GameObject> npc;
    private int oldtimevisit;

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    private void Awake()
    {
        npc = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Npc").ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < npc.Count; i++)
        {
            if (npc[i].GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>() != null)
            {
                agents.Add(npc[i].GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>());
            }
        }

        transporter = GameObject.Find("Pref_TransporterBlue");

        oldtimevisit = timeVisit;


        waypoints = new Waypoints();
        waypoints.points.Add(transporter.transform);
        waypoints.agents = agents;
    }

    void Start()
    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(timeVisit != oldtimevisit)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            Debug.Log(Random.Range(20,timeVisit));

            var timetowait = Random.Range(20, timeVisit);
            StartCoroutine(Waiting(timetowait));
        }

        oldtimevisit = timeVisit;
    }

    IEnumerator Waiting(int waitingtime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitingtime);

        DoSomethingWithNpcs();
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithNpcs()
    {
        waypoints.start = true;
    }
}
```

Last the ai script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    public float distanceToContinue;

    private float currentDistanceToPoint;
    private int lastPointIndex;
    private int goalPointIndex;


    void Start()
    {
        //Firstly check if the waypoints are set up correctly
        if(waypoints.points.Count < 1)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Set up the waypoints for this gameObject!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Now set up the path
            lastPointIndex = 0; //Start from the index 0
            this.transform.position = waypoints.points[0].position;
            goalPointIndex = 1; //Go to the [1] waypoint
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Calculate the distance and check if it should move to the next waypoint.
        currentDistanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
        if(currentDistanceToPoint <= distanceToContinue){
            //Save the old index, totally useless in this implementation though
            lastPointIndex = goalPointIndex;
            //Increase goal index to change the goal waypoint to the next, (Or maybe random one?)
            goalPointIndex++;
            if(goalPointIndex >= waypoints.points.Count)
                goalPointIndex = 0;
        }

        //Now move towards the current waypoint, Change this to fit your code with navMesh anyway I think I did a lot for you anyway
        transform.LookAt(waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
}
```

The problems :

- When making new instance in the BodyScan script for the Waypoints class I'm adding a waypoint to the points list and also assign agents to the agents list. but then when using breaking point in the ai script in the Start() function I see that the points list and the agents list both are empty. Why they are empty ?
- In the ai script it's using transoform but I want also to make that I will be able to use the agents list to move them and not only the transform of the script is attached to. For example if the ai script is attached to empty gameobject and I want to use the points and agents lists from the Waypoints class.

Both BodyScan and the AI scene are attached to empty GameObjects.

Even simpler in this screenshot I have two characters the one in t pose and the droid with the blue circle in the middle. and I want each one to move between other waypoints. one can move up the stairs and back the other move to the window and back :

[image: Simpler]

Comment: The way you've written this, each BodyScan script instance and each SimpleAI script instance have their own separate waypoint collections. So when BodyScan sets up its waypoints, that doesn't do anything to the completely separate waypoints collection in SimpleAI. Is that deliberate, or are you intending this information to be shared somehow?

Comment: @DMGregory  I'm intending this information to be shared somehow I want to have multiple characters moving between different waypoints. For example I added 20 cubes tagged them as "Waypoint" and I have 3 characters I want each character to move between different waypoints. For example character 1 will move between cubes 1 to 5 character 2 between 3 and 10 character 3 between 11 and 20

Comment: And do both these scripts control one character?

Comment: Each script group red or blue can have one or more characters. but the characters for each group will be belong to the same group waypoints. blue can have for example 1 or 20 characters and red can have 4 or 10 for example the BodyScan have one waypoint the transporter but could be 5 character moving between the first characters position and the waypoint.  Same for the red can have multiple waypoints and agents.

Comment: Even simpler in this screenshot in the link I have two characters the one in t pose and the droid with the blue circle in the middle. and I want each one to move between other waypoints. one can move up the stairs and back the other move to the window and back. https://imgur.com/a/FAyWVWr